# React app needs reload after login to load data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-chartjs

As the title suggests, I am developing an app with React, and the project is already configured in its basic structure (Login, Routes, Axios, etc).
I then started developing the first interface components.
After login (which works correctly) the user is redirected to the application dashboard containing charts and tables containing summaries.
I have the following problem ... when I arrive on the dashboard after login it is as if the bees I use to populate the charts and tables were not called and so I have to reload the page.
It is the first time this has happened to me and looking online and on the React documentation I could not find any solution.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

MY CODE:

- dashboard page:

```
import PageTemplate from "../templates/Template";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DashCard from "./DashboardCard" // eliminabile
import HomeDoughChart from '../charts_js/HomeDoughChart'
import HomeBarChart from "../charts_js/HomeBarChart";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { getDashboard_Data, getDashboard_Data_byYear } from "../../repo/dashboardRepo";

const DashboardPageNew = () => {

   const [chart, setChart] = useState([])
   const [barchart, setBarChart] = useState([])
   const [dashboardfilter, setDashboardFilter] = useState({year: "", tributo: "" });
   function handleYearChange(evt){
      setDashboardFilter({year: evt.target.value, tributo : dashboardfilter.tributo});
   }
   function handleTributeChange(evt){
      setDashboardFilter({year: dashboardfilter.year, tributo: evt.target.value});
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      const a = async () => {
         if(dashboardfilter.year === "" && dashboardfilter.tributo === "" ){
            const res = await getDashboard_Data();
            setChart(res.data.data);
         }else{
            
         }
         
      }
      a()
   }, [])

   useEffect(() => {
      const b = async () => {
         const res1 = await getDashboard_Data_byYear();
         setBarChart(res1.data.data);
      }
      b()
   }, [])

   return (

      <PageTemplate title={"Homepage del comune di '" + localStorage.getItem("tenant") + "'"}>
         <Grid container direction="row" justify="left" alignItems="center" >
            <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "stretch" }}>
               <form>
               <label>Filtra per anno di riferimento</label>
                  <select name="year" value={dashboardfilter.year} onChange={handleYearChange}>
                     <option value="">Tutti gli anni</option>
                     <option value="2022">2022</option>
                     <option value="2021">2021</option>
                     <option value="2020">2020</option>
                  </select>
                  <br/>
                  <label>Filtra per tributo</label>
                  <select name="tributo" value={dashboardfilter.tributo} onChange={handleTributeChange}>
                     <option value="">Tutti i tributi</option>
                     <option value="TARI">TARI</option>
                     <option value="3944">3944</option>
                     <option value="3945">3945</option>
                  </select>
               </form>
               {console.log("Anno:"+dashboardfilter.year+" Tributo:"+dashboardfilter.tributo)}
               <HomeDoughChart chart={chart} />
               <Grid container spacing={1} style={{ marginTop: '50px', marginLeft: '20px' }}>
                  <MaterialTable
                     options={{
                        search: false,
                        paging: false,
                        sorting: false,
                        responsive: true
                     }}
                     columns={[
                        { title: '', field: 'name' },
                        { title: 'Importo €', field: 'importo' },
                        { title: 'Atti', field: 'atti', type: 'numeric' },
                        { title: '%', field: 'percentage' }
                     ]}
                     data={[
                        { name: 'Totale pendenze', importo: Intl.NumberFormat('it-IT', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(chart.totaleDaPagare), atti: chart.attiTotali, percentage: '100%' },
                        { name: 'Totale pagamenti', importo: Intl.NumberFormat('it-IT', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(chart.totalePagato), atti: chart.pendenzePagate, percentage: parseFloat((chart.totalePagato * 100) / chart.totaleDaPagare).toFixed(2) },
                        { name: 'Rimanente', importo: Intl.NumberFormat('it-IT', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(chart.totaleNonPagato), atti: chart.pendenzeNonPagate, percentage: parseFloat((chart.totaleNonPagato * 100) / chart.totaleDaPagare).toFixed(2) },
                        { name: 'Non agganciato', importo: Intl.NumberFormat('it-IT', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(chart.totaleParziali), atti: chart.pendenzeParziali, percentage: parseFloat((chart.totaleParziali * 100) / chart.totaleDaPagare).toFixed(2) },

                     ]}
                     title="Consuntivo posizioni" />
               </Grid>
            </div>
         </Grid>
         <Grid container direction="row" justify="left" alignItems="center" style={{ marginTop: '70px', marginLeft: '20px' }}>
            <p>Consuntivi per anno</p>
            <HomeBarChart barchart={barchart} />
         </Grid>
      </PageTemplate>
   )

}
export default DashboardPageNew;
```

- axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import history from "../history";
//const apiUrl = `https://${localStorage.getItem("tenant")}.api.mspay.it/api/auth/`; //your api base url
const apiUrl = `https://test.mydomain.it/api/auth/`;
const proxyurl = "https://myproxy.io/fetch/"; //proxy for local testing, remove this in production version
function getHeader() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const expiration = localStorage.getItem("token_exp");
    if (expiration * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        history.push("/");
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        };
    }
    if (token) {
        return {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            useCredentials: true,
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',

        };
    } else {
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        };
    }
}
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    headers: getHeader(),
})

export default api;
```

- login code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import history from './../../history';
import getToken from "../../auth/auth";

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function LoginPage() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [alertState, setAlertstate] = useState({
        open: false,
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "center",
        severity: "success",
        message: "",
    });
    const { vertical, horizontal, open, severity, message } = alertState;
    const [loginObj, setLoginObj] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        try {
            await getToken(loginObj.username, loginObj.password);
            
            if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('token_exp')) {
                setAlertstate({
                    open: true,
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                    message: "Login Successfully.",
                    severity: "success",
                });
                history.push("/dashboard");
            } else {
                setAlertstate({
                    open: true,
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                    message: "Login failed. Please try again.",
                    severity: "error",
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            setAlertstate({
                open: true,
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "center",
                message: "Invalid Data. Please try again.",
                severity: "error",
            });
        }
    };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            onChange={(e) => {
                setLoginObj({ ...loginObj, username: e.target.value });
            }}
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            onChange={(e) => {
                setLoginObj({ ...loginObj, password: e.target.value });
            }}
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="button"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/signup" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code of login component?

Comment: @Prana, yes i'm editing the question with login code

Answer (score 1):

After successful completion of login, you need to set the headers in axios. There are several ways to do this. One of them is to export the same axios object in `axios.js` file and set the default headers in `login.js`

### axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import history from "../history";
//const apiUrl = `https://${localStorage.getItem("tenant")}.api.mspay.it/api/auth/`; //your api base url
const apiUrl = `https://test.mydomain.it/api/auth/`;
const proxyurl = "https://myproxy.io/fetch/"; //proxy for local testing, remove this in production version
function getHeader() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const expiration = localStorage.getItem("token_exp");
    if (expiration * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        history.push("/");
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        };
    }
    if (token) {
        return {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            useCredentials: true,
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',

        };
    } else {
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        };
    }
}
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    headers: getHeader(),
})

export default api;
export { axios }
```

### login.js

```
// rest of the imports

import { axios } from '../axios.js';

// rest of the code

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        try {
            await getToken(loginObj.username, loginObj.password);
            
            if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('token_exp')) {
                setAlertstate({
                    open: true,
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                    message: "Login Successfully.",
                    severity: "success",
                });
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                history.push("/dashboard");
            } else {
                setAlertstate({
                    open: true,
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                    message: "Login failed. Please try again.",
                    severity: "error",
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            setAlertstate({
                open: true,
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "center",
                message: "Invalid Data. Please try again.",
                severity: "error",
            });
        }
    };
```

*** Don't forgot to import the axios from your `axios.js` instead of from node_modules

Comment: Thans, i've tried this solution but i've the same behavior, after the login i need to reload the page

Answer (score 0):

### use axios interceptors

```js
import baseAxios from 'axios'

const axios = baseAxios.create({
    baseURL: cfg.baseUrl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'fa',
    },
})

axios.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('loginToken')
        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
        }
        return config
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)

export default axios
```